# Why we use ORM or ODM to manage any graphDB?

Tags: node.js, orm, orientdb, oriento

Hey everyone I am working on nodeJS app. I searched some modules to manage my database (orientdb).
My question is: Why we use any ORM or ODM (or why is it recommenced), because there is a module which can provide many functions to manage DB.
I am still confused what should I use orientorm (https://github.com/mav-im/orientorm) or oriento (https://github.com/codemix/oriento)

Thank in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the goal and depending on the ORM, ORMs have the advantage of adding support for:

- **schemas / models / collections**: this makes it easier to create all classes/properties and, in some cases, migrations;
- **validations**: make it easier to verify what gets saved in the DB.

All OrientDB ORM's I've seen for node.js expose Oriento, so that makes it easy to access the underlying oriento methods for doing more complex stuff.

Having said all this I recommend you try the [waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) ORM with [waterline-orientdb](https://github.com/appscot/waterline-orientdb) adapter. Waterline is an adapter based ORM with support for multiple databases (including support for **associations between databases**). Waterline-orientdb is the adapter for OrientDB which is based on Oriento. If at any point you need to use Oriento you can call `.getDB()` to access Oriento's instance.

Answer (score 0):

Oriento is much more mature and supported. I suggest you to go with it.

Comment: Hey Luca 
first orientrom is also using oriento as dependecy.
second i am also using some other databases(i.e  rfd ) as well.
 So what do you suggest for my development stack ?